# Xamarin forms iOS app wont build (failed to resolve system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I am using

Visual Studio Studio Community 2015 (Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2)

Xamarin   4.1.1.3 (34a92cd)
Xamarin.iOS   9.8.1.4 (3cf8aae)

When I build my iOS application I get the error

[image]

Failed to resolve "System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder" Ive updated everything to the latest versions, but cant seem to find anything that points to a current solution

Answer (score 0):

There are several Problems with this Error-Message, most of them after some automatically updates form Microsoft.

Some fixes:
- compile the broken libraries yourself
- cleanup \bin

Here is a link which was posted after a strange Discussion.
https://www.jimbobbennett.io/weird-goings-on-with-xamarin/

Here is the discussion i talked about
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23460/build-failure-after-update-failed-to-resolve-system-runtime-versioning-frameworkname

I had this problem months ago.... but i can´t remember the fix. Try to figur it out with these links.

g

Comment: newtonsoftJson seems to be a likely candidate but im already referencing the correct version I think. hmm the hunt goes on

Comment: im referencing 

    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>

Comment: Seems to be a problem with Java.Interop, also tried unlinking the project

Comment: and removed the reference to newtonsoft.json